# Speed up for loop, (dynamic) constrained index

Tags: c, loops

I have two for loops with constrains `nr` and `nc` and I want to speed up the code by only calculating the indices I really need to calculate. I have this two codes and I compile them with gcc -O3.

First one takes only about 3secs:

```
int i;
int j;
for(i=0; i<nr; i++){
    for(j=0; j<nc; j++){
        *(arr+i*nc+j) = fun(i,j);
    }
}
```

And a second function (which should be faster or at least not slower, because the number of loops is smaller or equal):

```
int i;
int j;
int oi;
int oj;

i = (px-d > 0) ? (px-d) : 0;
j = (py-d > 0) ? (py-d) : 0;

oi = (px+d < nr) ? (px+d) : nr;
oj = (py+d < nc) ? (py+d) : nc;


for(; i<oi; i++){
    for(; j<oj; j++){
        *(arr+i*nc+j) = fun(i,j);
    }
}
```

px,py and d are arguments of these functions.
The runtime:

first: ~3seconds

second: ~4.3seconds

In the second function there are some more instructions but they should be really cheap in comparison to the like 10.000 calls of the fun-function through the loop.
Do I miss something here? Does that "dynamic" initialisation of the i,j change the way gcc can optimize the code? Could I do something about it?

Thanks.

Comment: `i*nc` - you don't need to recalculate that each inner loop. `to the like 10.000 calls` - please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Others would like to test your code and compare the benchmarking or at best use [one of online services](http://quick-bench.com/). What should others do, to replicate the values you are seeing? What are the values of `oi`, `oj`? How is `px` `d` `py` `nr` `nc` related? What is `arr`? What does `fun` do, how is it related? Did you compare generated assembly code? How did you measured the time of execution?

Comment: 3 seconds ? That sounds like a lot to explain from just what you showed. How big are `nc` and `nr` ? How long does a single call to `fun` take (on average) ? How big/complex is a single item in your array ? What kind of hardware is this run on ?

Comment: Warning, in second code, `j` is not correctly initialized. Is this an [MCVE]?